# Linq select nested rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class PingtreeTier
{
    public BuyerType BuyerType { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MaxRequests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PingtreeNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    public int Seq { get; set; }
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public bool Weighted { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see PingtreeTier contains an `IEnumerable<PingtreeNode>` class. This PingtreeNode class has a property named Status. Using Linq, I need to select only the Tiers/Nodes where PingtreeNode Status = 'Active'.

Anyone help as I'm struggling with the syntax for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here:

```
var results = tiers.Where(t => t.Nodes.Any(n => n.Status == "Active"));
```

This will select any `PingtreeTier`s that contain at least one `PingTreeNode` with `Status` equal to "Active".

If you wanted to select only `PingtreeTier`s whose `PingTreeNode`s are *all* active, you could use the `.All` extension method instead:

```
var results = tiers.Where(t => t.Nodes.All(n => n.Status == "Active"));
```